# May I write Window Mobile Library in Visual Studio Express?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, windows-ce

To write a WM application, I have to use VS Pro cos I would need WM template and Emulator.
But if I just need to write a dll, is it possible to do it in VS Express?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The express SJUs of Visual Studio do not have the compiler pieces for Smart Device Development.  You need VS 2005 Standard or better or VS 2008 Professional of better.